# Set R_HOME for MAC OSX for application to access R

Tags: r, macos

I have an application that can call R from it.  It tells me error: "The location of the R installation must be set with the R_HOME environment variable"

I need to set up R_HOME to where R is located on my machine.  /usr/bin/R.

When I type echo $R_HOME I get a blank.  What is the best way to set R_HOME?  I have OSX 10.9.2 installed. If the path is set to /usr/bin/R will this be enough or is something more complex needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place it in your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
export R_HOME=$(which R)
```

Then from the command line try

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $R_HOME
```

For example, I see `/usr/bin/R`.

Comment: This is the right answer to a wrong question. R_HOME serves a different purpose: it is the installation directory, not the the directory where the R binary is, and R_HOME is actually set inside the R session. You can always look it up using 

    `$ R RHOME # shell`

or 

    `> R.home()   # inside R`

or 

    `> Sys.getenv("R_HOME") # also inside R`

Your solution works, but it is a solution to a program asking for the wrong thing entirely. The program should rely on $PATH, or use a different name for the environment variable holding the location of the R binary ...

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it needs the full pathname to the R binary? (see my comment above).
This is, on Unix-like systems, always `$R_HOME/bin/R`
Now, `$R_HOME` is usually  not supposed to be set directly (R sets it itself), but it may be that the program calling R knows that R can be found at `$R_HOME/bin/R`. In that case, do

```
export R_HOME=$(R RHOME)
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: How can I set  R_LIBS_USER to first value returned by: .libPaths(), Thanks!